# Select submit button of specific form for click event

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I have the following form, how can I select the submit button based on the form ID to be used for a click event?

```
<form id="login">
    <input type="text" name="email">
    <input type="text" name="password">

    <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

Something like the following works, but it can't just be `input[name=submit]` because there may be more than one on the page.

```
$('input[name=submit]').click(function (e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        console.log('clicked');

    });
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This will automatically select the form's submit control:

```
$('#login :submit').click(...);
```

http://api.jquery.com/submit-selector/

Cheers

Comment: ha, I tried this before and it didn't work. Didn't realize there has to be a space! thanks

Comment: You're welcome. If you feel I answered your question, please consider marking the answer accepted w/ the checkmark in the upper-left. :)

Comment: The selector page does mention that "*Because `:submit` is a jQuery extension and not part of the CSS specification, queries using `:submit` cannot take advantage of the performance boost provided by the native DOM `querySelectorAll()` method. For better performance in modern browsers, use `[type="submit"]` instead.*"

Answer (score 6):

Use :

```
 document.querySelectorAll("input[type=submit]")[0].click();
```

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
$('#login input[type="submit"]')
```

You can read http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/ for all CSS selectors.. (*jQuery supports all default selector + more http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/*)